# "Unexpected error from external database driver (1)."

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I have `.xlsx` file with 27,000 rows. When executing the SSIS package on the server I get the above error. I have tried running the package in `32-bit mode`, it did not work. Microsoft does not have a good explanation. I have installed access driver on my machine and on the server.

Comment: Trying the Access database engine 22016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the Ace Oledb driver 10 and install Ace 2016 version .The Security patch Microsoft provided in October 2017 is causing this issue. Test your SSIS package locally ,if everything is fine install Ace 2016 version on your server .

Here is the download link:

- [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)

Comment: even if you decide to write your own answer, you can mark it as correct even if it is yours. so question is marked as answered. Good Luck

Comment: why you are confused. why accepting and unaccepting my answer multiple time. If my answer solved your problem then accept it. Else you have the right to accept your own answer.

Comment: It is so easy. Good Luck +1 for the answer and +1 for the question it is helpful

Comment: Sorry , i am new at this. All i wanted was to accept my own answer . I will do better next time

Comment: one thing to take into coinsideration `Remove the Ace Oledb driver 10 and install Ace 2016 version` it is not true. `The Security patch Microsoft provided in October 2017 is causing this issue` this is the true part of the answer. which i mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming that you tried running in 32-bit, and you downloaded Access Database Engine and the issue is not solved*

This is caused by a windows security update, this is noticed in the [Microsoft Support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4050795/unexpected-error-from-external-database-driver-error-when-you-create-o), also they provided patches link.

There is a similar question on MSDN about this issue, read the accepted answers:

- [Unexpected error from external database driver (1)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/45ebe780-967e-4748-a146-9ec7a15626dc/unexpected-error-from-external-database-driver-1?forum=itmanager)

---

*Side Note: Try opening the Excel and saving it as new Excel workbook to ensure that the excel is not damaged*

Comment: Yes the problem is with security patch KB4041681. I fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused if the Excel file is in Read-Only mode. Changing the Read-Only mode will fix the issue.